# Express app.post request not responding to Postman POST request

Tags: javascript, express, postman

I'm trying to emit a simple POST request using Postman to my express app, however the post request is timing out.

Here is the request:

[image: <code>http://localhost:3000/?inviteCode=12</code>]

And here is the app:

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  if (req.body.inviteCode === "12") {
      res.json({value: "success"}) 
  } else {
      res.json({value: "fail"})
  }
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`)
})
```

`console.log(req.body)` prints out an empty object `{}`

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including `inviteCode` in the POST parameters in Postman (as seen in your screenshot, the key-value entry under the "Body" tab), instead you are passing `inviteCode` as a URL query parameter, which will be set in `req.query.inviteCode`.

To use it from the query parameter (in the URL), matching your Postman request:

```
app.post('/', (req,res) => {
  req.query.inviteCode === "99" ? res.json({value: "success"}) : res.json({value: "fail"})
})
```

Or to use it in the POST body, which requires fixing your Postman request:

```
app.post('/', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  req.body.inviteCode === "99" ? res.json({value: "success"}) : res.json({value: "fail"})
})
```

Comment: You are right but it's still failing when I send the right payload. Edited my question to reflect this

Comment: You have not added `inviteCode` key and value under the body tab in your Postman screenshot.

Comment: Hats off to you